# Correlating two time series to account for lag and lingering effects

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation, lags

I am trying to find the correlation between two time series, call them A and B. Let's pretend A has the number of successful advertising campaigns for each month for a company, and B has the company's revenue growth rates (year over year) each quarter. My hypothesis is that the effects of a successful advertising campaign would show up next quarter, and that there would be a lingering effect for about a year.

Based on my assumptions, would it be legitimate for me to try to cross-correlate the values in B and a moving average over a year shifted forward one quarter for the values in A? If not, why not, and what would be a legitimate way for me to test my hypothesis? I am using R, but am looking to make sure I am thinking about this correctly statistically.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, doing a cross-correlation is probably what you want to do. If your hypothesis is correct,  the cross-correlation function will peak at a lag of 1Q and slowly die away over the next few quarters.

However, interpreting correlation functions can be tricky, especially when you want to consider the uncertainties and significance. The points in the correlation function are NOT independent. There are a lot of things affecting quarterly sales besides advertising so you may need many-many years to see a significant effect. This would work much better if you had hundreds of companies to work with. I doubt that you will see any significant effect from one company over a handful of years especially the last few years which had so much volatility.

Comment: Yes! I agree with you about the example - this one is purely hypothetical. I am wondering, however, would it be legitimate to take a cross-correlation between a moving average and a regular time series? Also, does it mess anything up if my predicted variable is a growth rate? I am assuming this just changes the interpretation, but wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was overlooking that might screw up the validity.

Comment: I would not take a moving average. You don't really need to. Just calculate the cross-correlation function on a quarterly basis. If you signal is large enough (I have doubts) the function will peak at 1Q and drop off from there. If you really want to you could rebin the correlation function over 4 bins but I don't think that will buy you much in terms of statistics. If there were no correlation between the points, it buys you only a factor of sqrt(4)=2 in error.

Comment: But they are very correlated and so it will be much less.

Comment: The YOY issue is another things to worry about. You might be better just working with the raw values of EPS (or whatever). The trouble with using YOY growth rates, is that it is unclear whether the amount is due more to this year being good or last year being bad (of vice-versa).

Comment: Right. That is what I am afraid of. What if I only have YOY growth rates, though - is there a way to deal with the problem of not knowing whether the amount is more due to last year being bad or this year being good? using growth rates for the predictor variable too, perhaps?

Comment: Please let me know if I missed something, but would I be able to account for a lingering effect if I run this test without taking a moving average? i.e. successful campaigns don't just affect one quarter, they affect all quarters over a given time frame

Comment: If YOY growth rates is all you have, that will probably still be OK since advertising campaigns can't affect the past (though correlation could go the opposite way). Try it and see what you get.

Comment: The lingering effect is a hypothesis. If you just keep everything on a quarter basis, you will test whether it does drop off each quarter by looking at the profile. The measurements of the cross-correlation function at different lags already accounts for this effect.

Comment: Additional question - is it legitimate to perform a regression using the YOY growth rate as the predicted variable, and then lagged advertising campaign numbers as predictor variables? What could be the potential issues that arise with that?

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing as a correlation function. The only thing to keep in mind is that with a correlation function, you do not fit for the additive constant offset. Usually you subtract off the means and so in effect, you set the constant term to zero. But you can get it back simply by adding back on the constant mean that you subtracted off. One advantage of doing an explicit linear model would be that you have more options. You can weight the data or use robust regression or other variants which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure I fully understand. What do you mean by adding back the constant mean?

Comment: Just saying that it is possible to fit the slope and the offset of a linear model in separate steps.

Comment: But what would be the purpose of doing that?

Comment: And is anything complicated by the fact that I am using a growth rate as the predicted variable? Besides the issue we already addressed?

Comment: Well you asked about whether it made sense to do explicit regression instead of a correlation function. I said that they are very similar but not exactly the same. They can be made to be the same if you subtract off the mean first. That is all.